# Node.js large file resumable upload speed up

Tags: node.js, html, express

I trying to create server that can handle big (100M-1T) files upload at maximum speed. So, I do next steps:

1. On client side (browser) I split original file by 3 pieces and start to upload all pieces in parallel.
2. If same piece filed to upload due to network problems then I check chunk size that already partial written to disk on server and respond to client that server need chunk from x-->end bytes long. And client send chunk from x bytes from piece.
3. Then all pieces was successfully uploaded  thnen I need to marge it in to one final file.

This is good algorithm?